# XSLT selecting an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some XML markup that looks like the following:

```
  <Conf_Standings League="Atlantic Coast">
   <Listing>
      <Team>Syracuse</Team>
      <TeamID>C76</TeamID>
      <Record Type="Conference">
        <Wins>10</Wins>
        <Loss>0</Loss>
        <Win_Percentage>1.000</Win_Percentage>
      </Record>
      <Record Type="Overall">
        <Wins>23</Wins>
        <Loss>0</Loss>
        <Win_Percentage>1.000</Win_Percentage>
      </Record>
    </Listing>
    <Listing>
      <Team>Virginia</Team>
      <TeamID>D05</TeamID>
      <Record Type="Conference">
        <Wins>10</Wins>
        <Loss>1</Loss>
        <Win_Percentage>.909</Win_Percentage>
      </Record>
      <Record Type="Overall">
        <Wins>19</Wins>
        <Loss>5</Loss>
        <Win_Percentage>.792</Win_Percentage>
      </Record>
    </Listing>
</Conf_Standings>
```

When I loop through the listings using XSLT 1.0, I use something like the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Conf_Standings/Listing">
```

The problem I have is that at this point, I'm currently in the context of each individual `Listing` and can no longer reference the `League` attribute in `Conf_Standings`. If I try to do something such as:

```
"standings": [<xsl:for-each select="Conf_Standings/Listing">
      {
        "name": "<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@League)"/>"
      } 
...
```

The league name comes up empty. What's the right way to grab a hold of `@League` in my example above so that "Atlantic Coast" is selected once I'm inside of `Conf_Standings/Listing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parent axis and get the @Leage

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../@League)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use a variable before for-each to store the value and use it:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="attribute-leage" select="Conf_Standings/@League"/>
<xsl:for-each select="Conf_Standings/Listing">
... <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($attribute-leage)"/>  ...
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```